# does android accessibilityService take screenshot work on api lower than 30?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, accessibilityservice

I am using Android AccessibilityService to take screenshot using some method that has been added on api level 30 , I wonder to know if it works on api's lower than 30 or not

this is my overrided method

```
    @Override
    public void takeScreenshot(int displayId, @NonNull Executor executor, @NonNull TakeScreenshotCallback callback) {
        super.takeScreenshot(displayId, executor, callback);
    }
```

and this is where I call takeScreenshot method and it gives me the result by takeScreenshot CallBack

```
takeScreenshot(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY,
                getApplicationContext().getMainExecutor(), new TakeScreenshotCallback() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull ScreenshotResult screenshotResult) {

                Log.i("ScreenShotResult","onSuccess");
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.wrapHardwareBuffer(screenshotResult.getHardwareBuffer(),screenshotResult.getColorSpace());
                AccessibilityUtils.saveImage(bitmap,getApplicationContext(),"WhatsappIntegration");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i) {

                Log.i("ScreenShotResult","onFailure code is "+ i);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I am also interested in this question. If you find a solution, let me know, please

Comment: I found some solutions , one of them was some screenshot manager that gives you output file of taking screenshot therefor its good to use , but the concern is that only works on api 30 and geater. But the way I used was taking screenshot by perform Accessibiblity service global action TAKE_SCREENSHOT , in this case you should define listener to extract saved image file from screenshot folder that would be done with FileObserver

Comment: Good idea. Perhaps it will help me. Please tell me how to provoke this action (TAKE_SCREENSHOT) ? Using accessibility service. Can you give a short code? Thank you

Comment: Sure, you can simply perform global action within your service class like this: performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TAKE_SCREENSHOT);

Comment: Thank you - but it works, only on the API 28 and above. Sadly, but I need for 27

Comment: My pleasant , but I don't think so . As far as I know it should work on lower api s as well

Comment: Because it has been with Accessibility Service from beginning . Therefore it must work on every api that Accessibitlity Service works on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong. @Field requires API level 28 (current min is 27): android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService#GLOBAL_ACTION_TAKE_SCREENSHOT. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#GLOBAL_ACTION_TAKE_SCREENSHOT Added in API level 28

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, not.
I tried to using it on APIs lower than 31 and got the following error.

[image]

here is my XML:

```
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canTakeScreenshot="true"/>
```